# bootstrap 3, bootstrap editable 1.5.1 and select2 3.4.0 js not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, smarty, jquery-select2

In my project in smarty template we have used dropdown with multiple value selection. For that we have used below code:

Html code:

```
<p>Groups Allowed: 
                    <a href="#" data-type="select2" id="groups_allowed" data-name="groups_allowed" data-pk="7" data-title="Groups Allowed" data-url="/leads/update_agent_report_information/{$agent->report_per_id}" class="editable editable-click" style="width:400px;">
                    {if true eq isset($groups_allowed)}{$groups_allowed}{/if}
                    </a>
                </p>
```

JS Code:

```
$('#groups_allowed').editable({
        type: 'select2',
        pk : 7,
        url: '/leads/update_agent_report_information/individual_lead_id',
        title: 'Groups Allowed',
        name : 'groups_allowed',
        source:group_array,
            select2: {
               multiple: true,
               sortResults: function(group_array, container, query) {
                    return group_array.sort(function(a, b) {
                         a = a.text.toLowerCase();
                         b = b.text.toLowerCase();
                         if(a > b) {
                             return 1;
                         } else if (a < b) {
                             return -1;
                         }else{
                            return 0;
                         }
                     });
                }
            },
        inputclass: 'mySelect',
        emptytext : 'Add Group',
        value:{/literal}{if true eq isset($agent->groups_allowed_for_reports)}'{$agent->groups_allowed_for_reports}' {else} '' {/if}{literal}   
    });
```

It is working fine in FF but in chrome when list goes on increase it is disable drop down listing on click.

Comment: please remove `php` tag this question not belongs to php